# Find the sum using

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is as follows:

Find the sum:

$1\cdot2 + 2\cdot3  + ... +  (n-1)n$

What I have tried so far:

We can write $(n-1)n$  as $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-1)!}$ which we can also write as  $2\cdot\dbinom{n+1}{2}$

I believe it is possible to use the binomial theorem here, setting $a = b = 1$ in $(a+b)^n$. I am not sure how to proceed however.

Comment: $\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-1)!}=n(n+1)\neq n(n-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite $k(k+1)$ as $\frac{1}{3}((k+1)^3-k^3)-\frac{1}{3}$. Observe the mass cancellation (telescoping) when we add up.

*Another way:* As remarked in the post, we want 
$$2\left(\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2}\right).$$
We show that the sum of the binomial coefficients is $\binom{n+1}{3}$. That will show that our sum is $2\cdot\binom{n+1}{3}$, which simplifies to $\frac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)}{3}$.

There are $n+1$ different doughnuts in a row. We want to choose $3$ of them for a healthy breakfast. There are $\binom{n+1}{3}$ ways to do the choosing.

Let us count another way. Maybe the leftmost doughnut we choose is the first doughnut. Then there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose the other $2$.

Maybe the leftmost doughnut we choose is the second one. There are then $\binom{n-1}{2}$ ways to choose the other $2$. Continue. Maybe the leftmost doughnut we choose is the third from the right end. Then there are $\binom{2}{2}$ ways to choose the other $2$. We have shown that
$$\binom{n+1}{3}=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n-1}{2}+\cdots +\binom{2}{2}.$$

Comment: I may be mistaken but doesn't $\frac{1}{3}((k+1)^3-k^3)$ add $\frac{1}{3}$ to the original expression?

Comment: @patrickh:  You are not mistaken!

Answer (score 1):

$$1\cdot2 + 2\cdot3  + ... +  (n-1)n+\color{red}{n(n+1)-n(n+1)}=$$
$$=1(1+1)+2(2+1)+...+(n-1)n+\color{red}{n(n+1)-n(n+1)}=$$
$$=1^2+2^2+...+n^2+1+2+...+n-n(n+1)=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n(n+1)=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}-n(n+1)=\frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}$$